# Pseudo Inverse of Jacobians

Tags: matrices, jacobian, pseudoinverse

I'm trying to develop a solution for a minimization problem for a project. This requires me to use the following equation relating $\dot X$ and $\dot Q$ through the Jacobian matrix. If needed, Q is a set of three limb angles while X encapsulates the corresponding endpoint Cartesian coordinates.

$$\dot X = J \dot Q $$
Where
$$ J = \left[ \begin{matrix}
    \frac{dq_1}{dx_1} & \frac{dq_2}{dx_1} & \frac{dq_3}{dx_1} \\
    \frac{dq_1}{dx_2} & \frac{dq_2}{dx_2} & \frac{dq_3}{dx_2} \\
    \end{matrix} \right] $$

Now, In my solution, I end up with the following expression
$$ J^TJ\dot Q = J^T\dot X $$
Where $J^TJ$ is a symmetric square matrix. Is it possible now to conclude through some kind of positive definiteness properties of this matrix that it is invertible? If so, how? This one step should enable me to obtain an explicit relation between $\dot X$ and $\dot Q$.

Comment: the rank of $J$ is at most 2 and therefore the rank of $J^T J$ is at most 2 but it is a  $3\times 3$ matrix so it can't be invertible (which needs full rank)

Comment: You seem to know its not invertible by using "pseudo inverse" in the title...? Which doesn't match question body

Comment: The Jacobian isn't a square matrix, but $J^T J$ is. I'm looking to find out whether that is invertible. I need this information to find out the psuedoinverse.

Comment: You'll need to say what kind of pseudoinverse you're looking for, but I can guarantee you that $J^T J$ is not invertible. If $J$ has full rank (i.e. rank 2) then the invertible one is the $2 \times 2$ matrix, $JJ^T$

Comment: That's alright, thanks. It answers my question quite satisfactorily.

Comment: OK, glad to help :)